# React Js component constructor and visible state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I want to do is start that react component as invisible. So I try to do a constructor but in the constructor I get:

> ';' expected

and:

> 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type
> annotation.ts(2683) Registro.tsx(40, 10): An outer value of 'this' is
> shadowed by this container. 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because
> it does not have a type annotation.ts(2683) Registro.tsx(40, 10): An
> outer value of 'this' is shadowed by this container. 'this' implicitly
> has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.ts(2683)
> Registro.tsx(40, 10): An outer value of 'this' is shadowed by this
> container.

```
const RegistroNuevaCuenta: React.FC = ( ) => {

  constructor() {
  
    this.state = {
      childVisible: false
    };
  }

  const [text, setText] = useState<string>();
  const [number, setNumber] = useState<number>();

  return (
    <div className="contenedor_central">
      <strong>Completá tus datos</strong>
      
      <IonItem>
        <IonLabel position="floating">Nombre</IonLabel>
        <IonInput value={text}></IonInput>
      </IonItem>
      <IonItem>
        <IonLabel position="floating">Apellido</IonLabel>
        <IonInput value={text}></IonInput>
      </IonItem>
      <IonItem>
        <IonLabel position="floating">E-mail</IonLabel>
        <IonInput value={text}></IonInput>
      </IonItem>
      <IonItem>
        <IonLabel position="floating">Clave</IonLabel>
        <IonInput value={text}></IonInput>
      </IonItem>

    </div>
  );
};
```

How can I set a constructor in Jsx?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Constructor is only used in class based components. Looks like you are using functional component

Comment: There are two types of components - class and functional - read about them both on the [reactjs docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components)

Comment: I change it to a class but it does not hide:     class MouseTracker extends React.Component {

      constructor(props: Readonly<{}>) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          isHidden: false,
        };
      }

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of what you are trying to do, but you cannot mix Class and Functions.

Using a constructor mean you are inside a Class, out of it, you can't.

What I would is to set another state value just like you did for text and number. Then you can do something like

```
if (isHidden) return null;
```

But then you would have to handle how your component become visible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the default state directly in the `useState` call:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#declaring-a-state-variable

`const [childVisisble, setChildVisible] = useState(false);`

You are trying to use a constructor inside a functional component which cannot be done:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor